How do I get the AWS Glue Job CDK construct to update the script asset?
I have a Glue Job and an S3 Asset defined in CDK. The resources create correctly but the update of the script file does not trigger the Glue Job to update its script in the resource.
How do I get the job to update when I update the content of the asset?
    dynamodb_etl_job_script = s3_assets.Asset(self, "dynamodb-etl-job", path="assets/dynamodb-etl-job.py")

    etl_job = glue.CfnJob(self,
        f"etl-{dynamodb_table_name}-glue-job",
        name=f"ETL-{dynamodb_table_name}-glue-job",
        role=f"arn:aws:iam::{self.account}:role/{crawler_role_name}",
        command=glue.CfnJob.JobCommandProperty(
            name="glueetl",
            script_location=dynamodb_etl_job_script.s3_object_url,
            python_version="3"
        ),
        default_arguments={
            "--enable-metrics": "true",
            "--enable-spark-ui": "true",
            "--extra-py-files": "s3://aws-glue-studio-transforms-510798373988-prod-us-east-1/gs_common.py,s3://aws-glue-studio-transforms-510798373988-prod-us-east-1/gs_flatten.py",
            "--spark-event-logs-path": f"s3://{glue_asset_bucket.bucket_name}/sparkHistoryLogs/",
            "--enable-job-insights": "true",
            "--enable-observability-metrics": "true",
            "--enable-glue-datacatalog": "true",
            "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "true",
            "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-enable",
            "--job-language": "python",
            "--TempDir": f"s3://{glue_asset_bucket.bucket_name}/temporary/",
            "--enable-auto-scaling": "true",
            "--glue-asset-bucket-name": glue_asset_bucket_name,
            "--glue-database-name": glue_database_name,
            "--glue-table-name": table_prefix+dynamodb_table_name,
            "--dynamodb-table-arn": boto3_dynamodb_table.table_arn,
            "--dynamodb-table-name": dynamodb_table_name,
            "--glue-export-bucket-name": glue_export_bucket_name,
        },
        max_retries=0,
        timeout=glue_job_timeout,
        number_of_workers=glue_job_number_of_workers,
        worker_type=glue_job_worker_type,
        glue_version="4.0"
    )

